# How to open Visual Studio Code from the command line on OSX?

Tags: macos, visual-studio-code, command-line-interface

The [docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/codebasics#_launching-vscode) mention an executable called `code`, but I'm not sure where I can find that so I can put it on my path. The zip I downloaded from the VSCode site did not include any such executable. (I am able to run the `.app` just fine.)

Is this a Windows-only thing?

Comment: type in command pellet (`cmd+shift+P`): Type shell command to find Shell Command: Install 'code' command in PATH command

Comment: @CharlieParker When I type code, I am not able to find that shell command.

Answer (score 972, accepted):

From the [Visual Studio Code Setup page](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/setup/osx):

> **Tip**: If you want to run VS Code from the terminal by simply typing 'code', VS Code has a command, Shell Command: Install 'code' command in PATH, to add 'code' to your $PATH variable list.
>
> After installation, launch VS Code. Now open the Command Palette (F1 or <kbd>⇧</kbd>+<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> on Mac) and type `shell command` to find the `Shell Command: Install 'code' command in PATH` command.
>
> After executing the command, restart the terminal for the new $PATH value to take effect. You'll be able to simply type 'code .' in any folder to start editing files in that folder.

Comment: On a side note, vscode ver 0.10.11 didn't add anything to my PATH on win 10, like that page says it would. No biggie.

Comment: You can add an option -r to open it in a new tab in old window: `code -r <filename>`. Normally, that is what you want.

Comment: I'm using macOS Sierra 10.12.6. The `code` command fails to launch Visual Studio Code after I restart my laptop.

Comment: When I do this, VS Code creates a symlink called `/usr/local/bin/code`  which links to an executable in a temporary directory under `/private/var/folders`. After restarting my computer, that directory is deleted so the symlink goes away. I made a more persistent symlink with: `sudo ln -s  /Applications/Visual\ Studio\ Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/bin/code /usr/local/bin/code`. Assuming `/usr/local/bin` is in your `PATH` this will survive a restart.

Comment: code () { VSCODE_CWD="$PWD" open -n -b "com.microsoft.VSCode" --args $* ;} you can try adding this to /.zshrc if it doesn't work out.

Comment: Opening command palette is now `cmd + shft+ p`

Comment: For the Mac users, please put your VS code editor application in the Applications directory otherwise the code command won't work after reboot

Comment: After pressing f1 and typing shell  command, there are no options to click in the drop down. Any ideas?

Answer (score 426):

1. Download, install and open [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/download).
2. Open the Command Palette (<kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>⇧</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> on Mac) OR **View** ❯ **Command Palette**
3. Type `shell command` to find `Shell Command: Install 'code' command in PATH command`
4. Install it

---

Here's a complimentary GIF.

[image: Install Code on Command line]

After that, you can use `code` or `code .` in the terminal.

```
code
```

If you'd like to go a little bit further and learn a couple of great tips/tricks for using the VSCode CLI, I made [a YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uKCiAA4AJcI) on my workflows.

Comment: For whatever reason  (⌘ + ⇧ + P ) was not working but F1 did it.  Thanks!

Comment: After  (⇧⌘P), just an example, use the View:Toggle Integrated Terminal command.

Comment: ^That's not what is being asked here.

Comment: (⌘ + ⇧ + P ) didn't work for me, I had to use View -> Command palette to have data appear in the command palette search

Comment: ^You must be on windows or linux. Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> instead of <kbd>⌘</kbd> there.

Comment: I believe (⌘ + ⇧ + P ) is for if you are using the Sublime Text key mappings. Worked for me Otherwise you can just open the command palette from the top menu bar > View > Command Palette.

Comment: I have tried this and worked. However, Every time I restart my machine, code . is not recognized anymore

Comment: That's weird. File that as an issue on https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/

Comment: code () { VSCODE_CWD="$PWD" open -n -b "com.microsoft.VSCode" --args $* ;} you can try adding this to /.zshrc if it doesn't work out.

Comment: May I ask you where is the file which the PATH is added?

Comment: What if "Shell Command: Install 'code' command in PATH command" doesn't show up? Only two options populate:
1. (Preview) PowerShell Command Explorer: Focus on PowerShell Commands View
2. View: Show (Preview) PowerShell Command Explorer

Answer (score 57):

If you want to open a file or folder on Visual Studio Code from your `terminal`, `iTerm`, etc below are the commands which come as default when you install Visual Studio Code

To open Visual Studio Code from command line

```
code --
```

To open the entire folder/directory

```
code .
```

To open a specific file

```
code file_name
eg:- code index.html
```

Answer (score 40):

<s>We since updated the script to the following syntax to support multiple files and folders as arguments and to fix an issue with not detecting the current working directory properly:</s>

```
code () {
    VSCODE_CWD="$PWD" open -n -b "com.microsoft.VSCode" --args $*
}
```

**Update for our VS Code 1.0 release:**

Please use the command `Install 'Code' command in path` or `Install 'code-insiders' command in path` from the command palette (`View | Command Palette`) to make Code available to the command line.

Comment: Is there a way to make this work with sudo, such as: `sudo code`. I'm using VSCode to work on some NPM modules and need sudo to overwrite.

Comment: @BenjaminPasero see my answer for a version which works with mingw32. Please add to VSCode setup docs if possible.

Answer (score 29):

This was the tutorial I was looking for in this thread. It shows the way to open files in Visual Studio Code by writing code .

1.- Open the file

Bash

```
                open ~/.bash_profile
```

Terminal OS

```
                    open ~/.zshrc
```

2.- Add in your file the :

```
         code () { VSCODE_CWD="$PWD" open -n -b "com.microsoft.VSCode" --args $* ;}
```

3.- Reinicialize terminal and try in the folder you want to open

```
         code .
```

4.- Then you can use it as shown in this comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41821250/10033560

Comment: This was the only solution that worked for me. VS Code's CMD+SHIFT+P was not maintaining state.

Comment: Worked perfect!

Comment: code ~/.zshrc worked for me thanks

Comment: This is a good backup solution. For some reason the built in shell command was failing because of an access error, but this did it for me. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks! This is the best solution for the Mac M1 chip users.  When I tried the 'export code to path' method, I would only get an "illegal hardware instruction" error. This solution works beautifully.

Answer (score 28):

For me on Macbook Book Pro 2019 MacOS version 10.15.6, shortcut to open command palette in VSCode was `Shift` + `Command` + `P`.

On opening it one has to just write `install code` and press `enter`.

[image]

After that just open the terminal and type `code` your vscode will start opening.

Comment: worked for me in version 11 (2015)

Comment: This should be selected as the correct answer

Comment: Thanks Thomas, it doesn't matter as for as it helps people. Upvote does the job well :)

Answer (score 13):

I have a `~/bin/code` shell script that matches the command @BengaminPasero wrote.

```
#!/bin/bash
VSCODE_CWD="$PWD" open -n -b "com.microsoft.VSCode" --args $*
```

I prefix `~/bin:` to my `$PATH` which allows me to add a bunch of one off scripts without polluting my `~/.bash_profile` script.

Comment: in bash_profile can add a function.

<br>
`function code {
  VSCODE_CWD="$PWD" open -n -b "com.microsoft.VSCode" --args $*
}`

Comment: @Py_minion I specifically stated that I do this to avoid bloating my bash_profile... Also, this answer and the original question are from over 4 years ago, before the option to add to the path was in the application.

Answer (score 11):

> **Note**: Only for Windows Users.

As many folks already suggested ways to open code from command prompt using `code .` command. This will only open **Visual Studio Code Stable**  build.  But If you have downloaded **Visual Studio Code Insider** build/version (Which has all latest build/features but unstable version) then you need to follow below instructions in windows :

- Go to Control Panel\System and Security\System. Click on Advanced System Settings
  [image]
- Click on Environment Variables
  [image]
- Under System Variables tab, Click on Edit for Path Variable 
  [image]
- Add a **new** path `C:\Users\tsabu\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code Insiders\bin` 
  **(or)** 
  `C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code Insiders\bin` based on location at which you have installed vscode insider in your machine.
  [image]

   
  Open a **new** command prompt and type `code-insiders .` to open vscode-insider 
  build/version

Comment: The question is regarding OSX not windows, I don't think this is a relevant answer. But as you got 6+, so that means it is still helping some people out there.

Answer (score 10):

After opening VSC and pressing (Command + Up + P) I tried typing in "shell command" and nothing came up. In order to get "Shell Command: Install 'code' command in PATH command" to come up, you must do the following:

1. Press (Command, Up, P)
2. Type `>` (this will show and run commands)
3. Then type `Shell Command: Install 'code' command in PATH command`. It should then come up.

   Once you click it, it will update and you should be good to go!

[MacOS X Launch from Command Line docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/setup/mac)

Answer (score 8):

On OSX Mavericks I created a bash script named `vscode` (adapted from the `.bashrc` in [VSCode Setup](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/setup)) in `~/bin`:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [[ $# = 0 ]]
then
    open -a "Visual Studio Code"
else
    [[ $1 = /* ]] && F="$1" || F="$PWD/${1#./}"
    open -a "Visual Studio Code" --args "$F"
fi
```

`vscode <file or directory>` now works as expected.

Comment: This script will work if Code is closed, but if it is already open, it just brings it forward and doesn't switch to the new directory. Is there a way to correct that?

Comment: You could use open -n -a ... to open a new instance.

Answer (score 8):

If you are using **VS Code Insiders**:

```
code-insiders .
```

If you are using **VS Code**:

```
code .
```

Answer (score 7):

If you install Your vs code in Download folder you need to move the VS code to Application folder then open the vs code ,then press `shift` `+` `command` `+` `p` after you will see [image] the below image. Then you need to type `code .` Now you are good to go.

Answer (score 7):

Steps to run `code .` command in mac to start the VSCode app -

1. Open VSCode
2. Open command pallet(Cmd+Shift+P)
3. Enter `Shell Command: Install 'code' command in PATH` and select
4. You will get the notification saying `Shell command 'code' successfully installed in PATH.`
5. Restart the terminal and enter `code .`
6. This will open VSCode from the current folder files in it.

Answer (score 6):

Try this one

Open Visual Studio Code and press Command + Shift + P then type Shell in command palette now you are able to find this option like Shell Command : Install code in PATH from suggested list in command palette. Select that options.

Open VSCode via Terminal/Command Prompt

That's it.

Now open your terminal type.

$ code .

Answer (score 5):

You can use the `vscode:` protocol that [Visual Studio Code defines](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/command-line#_opening-vs-code-with-urls):

```
open vscode://file/full/path/to/project/or/file
```

You can also use

```
/Applications/Visual\ Studio\ Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/bin/code
```

if you do not fancy [modifying your path](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/setup/mac#_launching-from-the-command-line)

Answer (score 4):

I discovered a neat workaround for mingw32 (i.e. for those of you using the version of bash which is installed by git-scm.com on windows):

```
code () { VSCODE_CWD="$PWD" cmd //c code $* ;}
```

Comment: FYI: You should probably ask/answer your own separate question for Windows specifically for this, if there isn't already one.

Comment: Launch "git bash" (i.e. mingw32) and simply type it at the bash command prompt and hit enter. Now to use it `cd /c/some/path` and then `code .` If you want it to be set automatically every time then you run git bash then add it to your `~/.bash_profile`

Answer (score 4):

its very simple:

**Launching from the Command Line**

You can also run VS Code from the terminal by typing 'code' after adding it to the path:

Launch VS Code.
Open the Command Palette (⇧⌘P) and type '**shell command**' to find the Shell Command: Install 'code' command in PATH command.

source

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/setup/mac

Answer (score 4):

This is what worked for me on Mac OS Catalina -- found [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/294176/how-to-install-visual-studio-codes-code-command-permanently)  (thanks, Josiah!)

If you're on Mac OS Catalina, you need to edit your .zprofile instead of .bash_profile.

1. Edit your ~/.zprofile file: `vim ~/.zprofile`
2. Add the following code in it, on it's own line: `code () { VSCODE_CWD="$PWD" open -n -b "com.microsoft.VSCode" --args $* ;}`
3. Save the file: :wq
4. Re-run the updated file: `source ~/.zprofile`.
5. Test that running `code .` opens your current folder in VS Code!

Comment: On Mac OS Monterey also its .zprofile instead of .bash_profile.

Answer (score 3):

I ran: `open -a "Visual Studio Code" [folder-name]` to open a folder with my Visual Studio Code application. Folder name is optional if you just want to open the application. Not sure if this is exactly your use-case, but hope this helps!

Answer (score 3):

In my case I had to use an alias:

```
alias code="/<PATH TO VSCODE>/Visual\ Studio\ Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/bin/code"
```

You can add this alias in your `~/.bash_profile`.

Answer (score 3):

I added this to my `~/.profile`

```
alias vscode='/Applications/Visual\ Studio\ Code.app/Contents/MacOS/Electron'
```

then

```
. ~/.profile
```

afterwards I can just do

```
 vscode
```

from the terminal

Comment: Thanks for the comment, that worked for me. However, please correct the typo. There needs to be a space after the second backslash.

Comment: Worked for me and I modified it just now to have the space thanks @matrik

Answer (score 2):

Added this to **/usr/local/bin/code**, you might have to modify the path if they are different.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

CONTENTS="/Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents"
ELECTRON="$CONTENTS/MacOS/Electron"
CLI="$CONTENTS/Resources/app/out/cli.js"
ATOM_SHELL_INTERNAL_RUN_AS_NODE=1 "$ELECTRON" "$CLI" "$@"
exit $?
```

Make executable afterwards

```
sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/code
```

Comment: Many thanks this is the only way that it works on my machine.

I noticed that the editor would open the file `$CONTENTS/Resources/app/out/cli.js` itself.

I removed the references to CLI and it behaves as expected.

Answer (score 2):

I had this issue because of VS Code Insiders.
The path variable was there but I needed to rename the code-insiders.cmd inside to code.cmd .

Maybe this is useful to someone.

Answer (score 2):

For windows Users
just type in

```
>code .
```

More commands here
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/command-line

Answer (score 2):

If you're using `visual code insiders` and you want to open a file or folder in `Visual Studio Code insider`s from your terminal or any other command line tool then you can refer to the commands below which come by default inside `visual studio code insider`.

To open Visual Studio Code from command line

`code-insiders --`

To open the entire folder/directory

`code-insiders .`

To open a specific file

`code-insiders file_name`

eg:- code index.html

Answer (score 2):

VSCode now supports it out of the box [with version 1.58](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/126702). Just type:

```sh
$ cd path/to/your/directory
$ code .
```

Answer (score 2):

Currently, for macOS, the build-in Command Pallete <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>⇧</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> routine `Shell Command: Install 'code' command in PATH command` will create a symbolic link from `/usr/local/bin/code` to the Visual Studio Code.app executable `code`. Or, for VSCodium, from `/usr/local/bin/codium` to the VSCodium.app executable `codium`.

The `code` (or `codium`) symbolic link can be created directly from the command line:

```sh
### For Visual Studio Code
sudo ln -s  \
  "/Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/bin/code" \
   /usr/local/bin/code

### For VSCodium
sudo ln -s  \
  "/Applications/VSCodium.app/Contents/Resources/app/bin/codium" \
   /usr/local/bin/codium
```

The user alert "successfully installed in PATH" can be a bit misleading since the PATH variable is not actually modified by the `osascript` in this case. By default, `/usr/local/bin` is already on the macOS `$PATH` for the default shell `zsh`.

[image]

Note: A `ln -s` symbolic link is persistent and available across shells (bash, zsh, …). This approach avoids the need to tweak `$PATH`, add an `alias` or define some method `code () {…}`.

```sh
ls -l /usr/local/bin/cod*
# lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  68 Nov 13 11:56 /usr/local/bin/code -> /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/bin/code
# lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  60 Nov 13 11:53 /usr/local/bin/codium -> /Applications/VSCodium.app/Contents/Resources/app/bin/codium
```

Also, alternate link names (e.g. `vscode`, `vscodium`) can be used, if desired.

Configuration Used:

- macOS Ventura 13.6, Sonoma 14.1.1
- Visual Studio Code 1.84.2
- VSCodium 1.84.2

Answer (score 1):

The instruction given at [VS Code Command Line](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/command-line) for launching a path are incorrect; the leading colon shown in the example doesn't work. However, launching with a backslash terminated directory name opens the specified directory as expected.

So, for example,

> code C:\Users\DAVE\Documents\Programming\Angular\StringCalculator\src\

opens the Visual Studio Code editor in directory `C:\Users\DAVE\Documents\Programming\Angular\StringCalculator\src`.

**Important:** The terminal backslash, though optional, is useful, as it makes clear that the intend is to open a **directory**, as opposed to a file. Bear in mind that file name *extensions* are, and always have been, optional.

**Beware:** The directory that gets appended to the PATH list is the `\bin` directory, and the shell command `code` launches a *Windows NT Command script*.

Hence, when incorporated into another shell script, `code` must be **called** or **started** if you expect the remainder of the script to run. Thankfully, I discovered this before my first test of a new shell script that I am creating to start an Angular 2 project in a local Web server, my default Web browser, and Visual Studio Code, all at once.

Following is my Angular startup script, adapted to eliminate a dependency on one of my system utilities that is published elsewhere, but not strictly required.

---

```
@echo off
```

goto SKIPREM

```
=========================================================================

Name:               StartAngularApp.CMD

Synopsis:           Start the Angular 2 application installed in a specified
                     directory.

Arguments:          %1 = OPTIONAL: Name of directory in which to application
                          is installed

Remarks:            If no argument is specified, the application must be in
                    the current working directory.

                    This is a completely generalized Windows NT command
                    script (shell script) that uses the NPM Angular CLI to
                    load an Angular 2 application into a Node development
                    Web server, the default Web browser, and the Visual
                    Studio Code text editor.

Dependencies:       Unless otherwise specified in the command line, the
                    application is created in the current working directory.

                    All of the following shell scripts and programs must be
                    installed in a directory that is on the Windows PATH
                    directory list.

                    1)  ShowTime.CMD

                    2)  WWPause.exe

                    3)  WWSleep.exe

                    4)  npm (the Node Package Manager) and its startup 
                        script, npm.cmd, must be accessible via the Windows
                        PATH environment string. By default, this goes into
                        directory C:\Program Files\nodejs.

                    5)  The Angular 2 startup script, ng.cmd, and the Node
                        Modules library must be installed for global access.
                        By default, these go into directory %AppData%\npm.

Author:             David A. Gray

Created:            Monday, 23 April 2017

-----------------------------------------------------------------------
Revision History
-----------------------------------------------------------------------

Date       By  Synopsis
---------- --- --------------------------------------------------------
2017/04/23 DAG Script created, tested, and deployed.
=======================================================================
```

:SKIPREM

```
echo BOJ %~0, version %~t0
echo.
echo -------------------------------------------------------
echo Displaying the current node.js version:
echo -------------------------------------------------------
echo.
node -v
echo.
echo -------------------------------------------------------
echo Displaying the current Node Package Manager version:
echo -------------------------------------------------------
echo.
call npm -v
echo.
echo -------------------------------------------------------
echo Loading Angular starter application %1
echo into a local Web server, the default Web browser, and
echo the Visual Studio Code text editor.
echo -------------------------------------------------------
echo.

if "%1" neq "" (
    echo.
    echo -------------------------------------------------------
    echo Starting the Angular application in directory %1
    echo -------------------------------------------------------
    echo.
    cd "%~1"
    call code %1\src\
) else (
    echo.
    echo -------------------------------------------------------
    echo Starting the Angular application in directory %CD%
    echo -------------------------------------------------------
    echo.
    call code %CD%\src\
)

call ng serve --open

echo.
echo -------------------------------------------------------
echo %~nx0 Done!
echo -------------------------------------------------------
echo.
Pause
```

Answer (score 1):

$> open -a "Visual Studio Code" [file-name]

Answer (score 0):

**link your currentily folders to vscode.**

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

; Directory\Background\shell => on empty space

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell\vscode]
"Icon"="C:\\current-folder-vscode\\Code.exe,0"
@="VsCode"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell\vscode\command]
@="C:\\current-folder-vscode\\Code.exe ."

; Directory\shell => on a folder

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\vscode]
@="VsCode"
"Icon"="C:\\current-folder-vscode\\Code.exe,0"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\vscode\command]
@="C:\\current-folder-vscode\\Code.exe ."
```

Comment: OP wanted a OSX solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you install VS CODE using `snap`. You will need to add `/snap/bin` in your PATH environment variable.
so - open your `.bashrc` or `.zshrc`
and add `/snap/bin` in your PATH environment variable

reload terminal,
and than `code` comand will start it

Answer (score 0):

For Windows you can use Command:

```
start Code filename.extension
```

The above line works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Just update your python to python3.9 i did that and it worked for me.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).