# Cannot install extensions in visual Studio code

Tags: linux, visual-studio-code, archlinux

I am an user of Arch Linux and my problem is that I am unable to install extensions. I followed the Microsoft pages which says that I should click ctrl+P and then write `ext install (package what I'm looking for)` so I did that.

After clicking "install extension" nothing happend that is why I tried several times with other extensions with no success. The bar "install" has shown but when I clicked on it nothing happend as well. My visual-studio-code was installed via aur 
 [Visual-Studio-Code aur page.](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/visual-studio-code)

I do not think it is connected with installation of visual-studio-code. I will be really thankful for a help with installation of extansions. Sadly no errors where shown in other way I would put it there down here. Please forgive me my english. I am not a native.

Answer (score 2):

It is really strange but after few reboots I successfully installed extansion. I did not know what caused the problem, but it works fine now.

Answer (score 2):

After it failed in the gui, I was able to install it with the `code` command line option.

```
code --install-extension lukehoban.Go
```

This is not a definitive answer, just "it worked for me."

For OS X users who have this issue, install `code` here: [How to open Visual Studio Code from the command line on OSX?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29971053/how-to-open-visual-studio-code-from-the-command-line-on-osx)

Answer (score 2):

It looks like VS Code is not installed for being used as admin in linux, and it means that by default the extensions folder doesn't have permissions to write, so when a user tries to install specific extension, it's not allowed.

What I did was the following, but you can modify the permissions as you prefer:

```
sudo chmod 777 -R $HOME/.vscode/extensions/
```

I hope it helps to some linux users.

Comment: this worked for me after long hours of searching. I'm using ubuntu 21.10

Answer (score 1):

I think the right combination is **Ctrl + Shift + P**, or **Ctrl + P** but you have to type `>`.

[image: Installing tslint extention]

Comment: dont working for me, `no command matching` (ArchLinux Manjaro)

Comment: type *ext install*, then hit enter and after that type name of the extension

Comment: yeah, i know, ant this is not working for me. I reload package from `Aur`, and reinstall. Then vscode start,and working functionally.

Comment: I am not using vscode from AUR for this reason. Just download it from official site.

Comment: From official, is not working for me :) Only from `Aur`.