# VS code giving error when installing extension

Tags: visual-studio-code

Hi guys im encountering an error when I try to install extension for VS Code in elementary. It gives an error as `Failed to install 'felixfbecker.php-intellisense'` when i try to install by downloading manually it says `ENOENT: no such file or directory, mkdir`

Inside the developer console it shows the same error for 1st method also. I have installed VS Code using the deb file with sudo.

Comment: Please work with the authors, https://github.com/felixfbecker/php-language-server/issues

Comment: @LexLi its not a problem with that particular extension i cannot install any extension. I think its a problem with th permissions.

Comment: VSCode is only officially supported on a few major operating systems. So it is possible to break on certain rarely used ones. If any extension gives the same error, you'd better contact the OS vendor for assistance.

Answer (score 0):

It was a permission issue solved it using
[this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61582005/12057928)