# Add VSCode portable location to PATH

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am using a portable version of VSCode, which means that the VSCode installation directory is not on PATH. However, quite a few VSCode extensions, scripts, etc., assume that if you run the command "code" or "code.exe" you will get a VSCode from somewhere. Generally you won't find one, or worse, if there is a default version install, you will find the wrong one. How can I add VSCode's base directory to PATH? It seems like there is a way in MacOS, with the "Install code in PATH" command, but there doesn't seem to be one for Windows.

Answer (score 0):

As of July 2023, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44269659/20107918) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61636873/20107918) don't seem to work well for `VSCode Portable`.
What works is an amendment of [this, editing the %PATH%](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65831863/20107918).
Essentially, the `bin` is not required as `Code.exe` is now in the main folder.

VSCode: 1.80
For Windows: Go to Environment Variable, add `"path_to_vscode\VSCode-win32-x64-1.80.0"` to `PATH`; whether `user variable` or `system variable`.

Alternatively, create a `code` variable and add the portable VSCode path.
This [gif provides visual illustration](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71060813/20107918).
***However, do not include the `bin` subfolder!

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer I was looking for. Most of the previous answers missed that I cuoldn't add the portable folder location to the system PATH because I had multiple versions of VSCode installed.

The answer that worked was here:
https://fabianlee.org/2021/12/23/vscode-add-a-directory-to-the-terminal-path/

Namely, you add a setting in the settings file called "terminal.integrated.env.windows" and add the folder to the PATH variable like so:
“c:\temp\mydir;${env:PATH}”