# Why isn't installing VS Code's `code` command on macOS permanent for me? Does it depend on where I installed VS Code to?

Tags: macos, visual-studio-code, macos-sierra

I just followed the top-voted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29971053/how-to-open-visual-studio-code-from-the-command-line-on-osx) and successfully installed Visual Studio Code's `code` command in my terminal.

However, the `code` command fails to launch Visual Studio Code every time after I restart my MacBook Pro.

```
~ code
zsh: command not found: code
```

Is it possible to install `code` permanently so that I don't have to install it every time I turn on my MacBook Pro?

```
~ where code
/usr/local/bin/code

~ ls -l /usr/local/bin/code
lrwxr-xr-x  1 myName  admin  167 Aug  5 13:41 /usr/local/bin/code -> /private/var/folders/bh/525lnbns1213cx2651s97my00000gp/T/AppTranslocation/EA379FC4-05D2-4739-BE49-1D8870E47B8A/d/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/bin/code
```

I also find out that the folder `EA379FC4-05D2-4739-BE49-1D8870E47B8A` get deleted after I restart my laptop.

This is the reason that I cannot run `code` after the laptop is restarted.

Why is `code` installed in a temporary folder?

My MacBook Pro's version is *macOS Sierra version 10.12.6*

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The reason that `code` get installed in a temporary folder is that I placed `Visual Studio Code.app` in `Downloads` folder.

After I moved it to `Applications` folder, launched it, and installed code command, the `code` is not installed in a temporary folder anymore.

Answer (score 3):

you can this code in visual studio code command palette to register shell command.
    Open the command palette.
    shell command
 and run this command to install 'code' command
    install 'code' command in PATH
And then restart terminal

Comment: no. this is what the question post says that the asker already did, and the whole problem is that this is not working permanently. this answer has no actual value to the question here.