# How to open VS Code from command line on macOS?

Tags: macos, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to figure out how to open the Mac version of VS Code from the terminal command line on my Mac and this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29971053/how-to-open-visual-studio-code-from-the-command-line-on-osx) here says says to open the Command Pallete and issue either of these two commands:

```
shell command

install code
```

On my computer, both commands result in the response "No matching commands".  Do I need to install any special extensions to get this to work?  I'm running macOS 11.1 and VS Code 1.52.1.

Comment: After installation, launch VS Code. Now open the Command Palette (F1 or ⇧+⌘+P on Mac) and type shell command to find the Shell Command: Install 'code' command in PATH command

Comment: Did you type `>shell command` or just `shell command`? According to the [VSC docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/setup/mac) you should be able to just type that command.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/setup/mac has a discussion on how to do it.

Here is a quote from the document.

Instead of running the command above, you can manually add VS Code to your path, to do so run the following commands:

```
cat << EOF >> ~/.bash_profile
# Add Visual Studio Code (code)
export PATH="\$PATH:/Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/bin"
EOF
```

Start a new terminal to pick up your .bash_profile changes.

Note: The leading slash \ is required to prevent $PATH from expanding during the concatenation. Remove the leading slash if you want to run the export command directly in a terminal.

Note: Since zsh became the default shell in macOS Catalina, run the following commands to add VS Code to your path:

```
cat << EOF >> ~/.zprofile
# Add Visual Studio Code (code)
export PATH="\$PATH:/Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/bin"
EOF
```

Comment: Just a note to remind others to be sure you've actually been running VS Code from your Applications folder. :)

I had been using Alfred to launch code and never paid attention to the fact that I never actually dragged it from my Downloads folder into Applications! So, of course, updating the path in my profile never made a difference.

Answer (score 1):

Similar to above, except take out the '' in front of $PATH since that will cause the dollar sign to be treated like a normal dollar sign which will kill your system. You can simply add the line

```
export PATH="${PATH}:/Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/bin"
```

to your .zshrc if on Mac, which should effectively be what that command line does argument does if you take out the backslash.