# CODE . command no longer works in terminal

Tags: macos, visual-studio-code, terminal, macos-monterey

Yesterday, the "code ." command was working perfectly fine. Overnight I did update my Mac to Monterey and now, I'm not understanding the exact reason why this command no longer works. I've already dragged the VS Code app to my applications folder, done CMD + SFT + P and successfully installed in PATH. When I try the command, I get the following message in my terminal.

```
/usr/local/bin/code: line 6: python: command not found
/usr/local/bin/code: line 10: ./MacOS/Electron: No such file or directory
```

Any advise would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is a duplicate question.
Below one can explain all the details you want.
Please refer to: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29971053/how-to-open-visual-studio-code-from-the-command-line-on-osx#:~:text=For%20me%20on%20Macbook%20Book%20Pro%202019%20MacOS,and%20type%20code%20your%20vscode%20will%20start%20opening](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29971053/how-to-open-visual-studio-code-from-the-command-line-on-osx#:%7E:text=For%20me%20on%20Macbook%20Book%20Pro%202019%20MacOS,and%20type%20code%20your%20vscode%20will%20start%20opening).

Comment: This is not a duplicate question since it's stating `code` no longer works while the linked question is merely asking how to do it. Also he states he already tried 'CMD + SFT + P' and it says it is successfully installed in PATH which is the solution given in the link you gave..

Comment: This link provided by @SeanH is the answer, you need to follow the instruction in the answer and it works :)